# Excel Mobile Data Entry Form

Tags: excel, ms-access, sharepoint, onedrive, powerapps

I am trying to create a data entry "app" to collect daily readings across our site. Here are the three biggest constraints:

- Software - ideally, we would use some software within the Microsoft 365 Suite, mainly because those are the only approved apps on site. It may be possible to use open source software, but that might raise some flags in terms of security. So my thoughts are to use either Excel or Access.
- Cost - ideally, we **do not** want purchase any additional software licenses. I would try and create something with Power Apps, but we do not have the licensing for an Azure or SQL server to store the data. I could be missing something here though.
- Mobile-Friendly - finally, it needs to work on an Android tablet. Currently, we collect readings using pen and paper. The whole idea of this is to move towards using a tablet.

The easiest approach would be to create an Excel spreadsheet, save it on OneDrive, and edit the spreadsheet. I don't love this option because we are collecting 100's of data points each day. This would end up with a very wide spreadsheet that will be cumbersome to navigate.

The other option I looked into was creating an Access database and accompanying form and storing it on SharePoint. However, it seems Microsoft has stopped supporting Access databases on SharePoint.

I have created data entry forms using VBA, similar to [this](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-add-a-userform-to-aid-data-entry-in-excel/), but these do not work on mobile.

Is it possible to create a data entry form in Excel that also works on the Android version of Excel? Are there other alternatives I am not thinking of?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to create a data entry form in Excel that also works on the Android version of Excel? Are there other alternatives I am not thinking of?

Microsoft Forms does the job when created from OneDrive on mobile browser. Side note: the form I just created and the response I submitted have now disappeared from my OneDrive.

I also saw some people using Power Automate to save responses from a form into an Excel file (every reponse).

Comment: Please show us the code so we can try it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

I am engaged in just this kind of project also.  I have written an app in PowerApps, built an Excel spreadsheet and stored it in OneDrive, and am running it (the app) on an iPad.  The design differs somewhat from your description of directly presenting a spreadsheet to the user (which I think PowerApps could do) because I don't want users having direct access to the data.

Edit:  You do not need Azure or SQL, unless you are storing tons of data.  Excel can be a satisfactory data storage location for modest uses.

I found the learning curve for PowerApps to be quite steep, as it's a different paradigm than line-by-line coding.

I think this is a more user friendly way to collect data than trying to run an Excel form, and once you get it made and polished, you'll look like a pro :)

I am by no means an expert but if you need some tips I'll do what I can to help.  It sounds like we are at similar developmental stages.